# Calling stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, sybase, callable-statement

Good Night in my timezone.

I am using Sybase ase 15, and I have a stored procedure with two input parameters both `VARCHAR`, basically inside the stored procedure I use dynamic SQL, something like this:

```
@cmd = 'select * from TABLE where COL IN'+@PARAM1+'AND COL2=@PARAM2
EXEC(@cmd)
```

I call this procedure using JDBC like this way:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call MyStoredProcedure(?,?)}");

stmt.setString(1, "'''0'',''1'''");
stmt.setString(2, '''fr''');
stmt.executeQuery();
```

It throws me an error informing that the call is malformed.

But if I run the call directly in the IDE like this :

```
EXEC  MyStoredProcedure'''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7''','''fr'''
```

It runs without any problem, so i guess that there is some problem with the character escaping i guess.

Anyone had experience this problem ?

With the best regards

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although in the first parameter i just use integer in fact in the database they are defined like VARCHAR that is why i pass with quotes

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify IN and OUT parameters:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

See if following the tutorial helps.

I would also comment that you only have two parameters, but your query passes in strings that appear to be more.  It's ugly, misleading, and appears to break first normal form.